# Reason for different color perception in left/right eyes?

Tags: human-eye, perception

What could be the reason for a difference in color perception between the two eyes of an adult individual without any known eye conditions? In particular, a difference in the perceived color temperature in each individual eye and an average of the two when looking through both eyes.

Comment: It may be advisable to remove any reference to self. At Biology SE we explicitly discourage self-help questions, as we support seeking professional advise. However, we are happy to share information on general scientific questions :)

Comment: This is not a personal health advice question even though the OP has used a personal example. Therefore I suggest that personal references may be removed to avoid that confusion.

Comment: Edited accordingly, first time posting outside of code/math questions.

Comment: Most likely, tumor. Also, there is asymmetry between left/right hemispheres, so why not eyes, which are also central nervous system

Comment: @aandreev Why is tumor most likely? Folks can reproduce this phenomenon by [lying down](http://www.washingtoncitypaper.com/articles/45840/can-colors-look-different-when-viewed-by-each-eye-colorblindness/), and there's some variability in [normal people](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1755-3768.1974.tb00382.x/pdf) (title: "Inter-eye comparison on the 100 hue test" if unavailable).

Comment: Good question. I've noticed this difference since my childhood.